# Jenkins TFS plugin not retriving the sources again after workspace was deleted

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I created a job to get sources from TFS and build the project. Everything worked, until I marked "delete workspace before/after build start/end" in the job. Now I getting "Finished getting version '...'. Retrieved 0 resources". How
to tell Jenkins to re-download the project every time the build starts ?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 7):

Configure > Source Code Management > Advanced > Uncheck "Use Update"
The next build should pull everything down again

In my case, this setting was preventing the download after deleting workspace.  Seems like it should recognize that the workspace was deleted and start over.  I'd consider this a bug in Jenkins.